# Melhor GUI Designer IDE

Tags: c++

Atualmente estou usando o Visual Studio 2012, e para criar aplicações de janelas, preciso usar C++/CLI, mas vi que está ultrapassado(wikipedia). Qual seria outra alternativa? o WxWidgets é recomendado?

Comment: Qual a sua definição de "melhor"? E qual a origem de ser "ultrapassado"?

Comment: Pra C++ recomendo uma olhada na Qt, que vai muito além das janelas. Agora, é uma pergunta complicada, pois atrai respostas de "evangelização", tanto por ser muito aberta quanto por depender de opiniões.

Answer (score 2):

o wxWidgets é excelente e bastante completo. Vc também tem várias outras bibliotecas de componentes para escolher.

Uma boa página pra começar é esta aqui: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits
esta compara com o wxWidgets:
https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Compared_To_Other_Toolkits

Agora não confunda biblioteca de componentes com GUI para montar telas. São 2 coisas separadas. 
Nenhum software para montar telas vai atender vc de forma completa. Logo logo a tela fica complexa demais para que qualquer montador de telas acompanhe. Vc pode usar o wxFormBuilder ou o wxSmith do Code::Blocks pra montar a versão inicial. Depois pega o código e coloca no seu programa incluindo os componentes futuros "na mão".

Comment: o CodeLite tem um editor de GUI mais atualizado que o wxFormBuilder e o wxSmith. **[Link](http://wxcrafter.codelite.org/)**.

Comment: Minha opinião é que que esta biblioteca é muito ruim. A "resposta" é totalmente uma opinião.